# Primary Output not Found while creating Setup File

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am trying to Create a setup File for my project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
I have added  Setup Project Template to the Existing Project,But i couldnt Find Primary Output when i right click on Application Folder in the File System Editor ,i could Find only Content Files in it.

Can you suggest me an idea to get this done ?
Iam  new to .net

Steps I have Tried...

Step1:
Opened my existing Project

Step2:
Added new Project to the Existing Project

Step3:
Selected Setup Project Template

Step4:
Right Clicked on the Application Folder in the File System Editor,but I couldn't find Primary Output in it.

Comment: can you write the step tried in your query ?

Comment: I have added the Steps which i have tried ,I hope i have make it clear now